# Can somebody please help me translate this Metzudat David commentary on Yirmiyahu?

Tags: yirmiyahu--book-of

I'm studying Yirmiyahu and having some trouble translating this passage of the commentary on [12:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jeremiah.12.4?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=en). I'm bolding the parts that I can't understand, but including the paragraph for context. Can somebody please help me translate? (I also can't figure out what נ״נ stands for for the life of me). Thank you.

> עד מתי. זהו תשובת המקום כאומר הלא הועמד להיות רצועת מרדות על ישראל להיות שבט אפי כי עד מתי תהיה ארצי נשחתה ועשבה יבשה **בסבת רשעת יושבי בה וכלתה בהמות ועוף כי לא תרבינה בארצם גמול פשעם באומרם שאני איני רואה אחריתם לדעת מה יהיה בסופם וכאומר וכי כן תהיה ארצי נשחתה עד עולם לכן יבא נ״נ ויגלה אותם מארצם וימורק עוונם וישובו אל ארצם ותהיה אז ארץ חמדה כמאז**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bolded section is the commentary on the second part of the verse. I added some punctuation and separated it into sections to make it clear which part of the verse he is commenting on.

> מֵֽרָעַ֣ת יֹֽשְׁבֵי־בָ֗הּ
>
> בסבת רשעת יושבי בה

(paraphrasing "from" as "because of")

> סָֽפְתָ֤ה בְהֵמוֹת֙ וָע֔וֹף
>
> וכלתה בהמות ועוף, כי לא תרבינה בארצם גמול פשעם

He gives the reason why the animals will perish: they won't increase in their land as punishment for their sin (their sin = sin of יושבי בה).

> כִּ֣י אָֽמְר֔וּ לֹ֥א יִרְאֶ֖ה אֶת־אַֽחֲרִיתֵֽנוּ
>
> באומרם שאני איני רואה אחריתם לדעת מה יהיה בסופם

Another straightforward paraphrase: They say that I (God) don't see what will happen in their end.

Now he explains the entire verse from the beginning:

> וכאומר: וכי כן תהיה ארצי נשחתה עד עולם? לכן יבא נ״נ ויגלה אותם מארצם וימורק עוונם וישובו אל ארצם ותהיה אז ארץ חמדה כמאז

As if to say (God is the speaker here): "Will my land really be destroyed forever like that?" (וכי introduces a question; here he is explaining the beginning of the verse עַד־מָתַי֙ תֶּֽאֱבַ֣ל הָאָ֔רֶץ).

Since this is a rhetorical question, he gives the assumed answer: "[No,] and so Nebuchadnezzar (נ"נ = נבוכדנאצר) will come and exile them and their sin will be expunged, and they will return to their land, and then it will be a desirable land as before" (and therefore the land will not be barren forever).